# How to make gauge chart in android?

Tags: java, android, charts, gauge

I want to make gauge chart in android. I referred the following two sites

- http://www.fusioncharts.com
- http://www.amcharts.com

But both of them didnot help

What i am looking is to built something like this

[image]

Comment: Do you need the gauge to be dynamic or just the indicator?

Comment: is this what you are looking for

Comment: i need dynamic type gauge chart.

Answer (score 0):

There are various charting libraries available, but most of them lack support for Gauge chart

Few which have Gauge Support are

- [Android GaugeView library](http://android.codeandmagic.org/android-gaugeview-library/)
  [image]
- [JFree Chart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html)
  [image]

  If there are issues, Do Leave a Comment!!

Comment: i tried this chart but it doesn't work in android.this chart is showing with coding in this site.www.amchart.com

Comment: are you talking about amchart??

Comment: i think you have a problem, both the website/chart engine you mentioned are based on `javascript`, there are specific to Web Platform. They are not for android platform, unless you are up for some crazy code to get actually chart via a web call.

my advice forget the amchart and fusionchart, should go wtih native library, since you want chart in android

Comment: i am getting all chart by using webview in android like pie3d,column3d but didn,t get gauge chart.

Comment: did you get the pie3d and other using the same amchart??
are you doing web call or loading page for displaying graph and charts??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44905/discussion-between-akhil-jain-and-dharmendra)

Comment: yes i got four chart Column3D,pie3D,Doughnut3D,Pareto3D but this time i have work for gauge chart so i am asking

Comment: please join the room, for further discussion

Comment: I think you should have better specified your question if you planned to get your chart using webview... It's misleading for people looking for android Gauge Widgets...

Answer (score -2):

If you are looking for HTML5/jquery gauge you can try jqChart's radial gauge - http://www.jqchart.com/jquery/gauges

It has great functionality and lots of examples.

Disclaimer: I work for jqChart.

Best,
Maxim Milev